# Flatlist not scrolling react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase, react-native-scrollview

for some reason my flatlist is not scrolling and I'm not sure why. Would love any tips!
Here is the code for the flatlist:

```
return (
      <Layout>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text size="h1">Explore</Text>
        </View>
            <FlatList contentContainerStyle={styles.cards} data={events} renderItem={({item}) =>
                <EventCard event={item} keyExtractor={event => event.id} click={() => {
                navigation.navigate("FullCard", {
                  event: item
                });
                }}/>
            } />
      </Layout>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    padding: 10,
    display: "flex",
    marginBottom: 10
  },

  cards: {
      alignItems: "center",
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height/1.2
  },
});
```

Here is the main page where the flatlist gets imported:

```
export default function ({ navigation }) {
    return (
            <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Explore">
                    <Stack.Screen name="Explore" options={{headerShown: false}}>
                        {props => <Explore {...props}/>}
                    </Stack.Screen>
                    <Stack.Screen name="FullCard" options={{headerShown: false}}>
                        {props => <FullCard {...props}/>}
                    </Stack.Screen>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Directly give you component in `Stack.Screen` and `props` will automatically access your screen.

```
export default function ({ navigation }) {
    return (
            <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Explore">
                    <Stack.Screen name="Explore" options={{headerShown: false}} component={Explore}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="FullCard" options={{headerShown: false}} component={FullCard}/>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
}
```

FlatList `contentContainerStyle` style should be as below

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    padding: 10,
    display: "flex",
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  cards: {
      flex:1,
      alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: Hmm... I followed your suggestions but scroll still isn't working. Could there be some other factor causing this?

Comment: use <View>  instead of <Layout> and check it

Comment: That did the trick along with setting flex=1 in the view container! Thank you!